# Can't compile because of types when using nub, map and take

Tags: haskell

I've got this simple function:

```
bombplaces::Int->[(Int,Int)]->[(Int,Int)]
bombplaces bombCount listOfPossiblePoints = nub (map (take  bombCount) (perms listOfPossiblePoints))
```

bombs are (x,y) (carthesian points)

i need to get an all permutations and take only first few (bombCount) points.

I'm getting following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Int,Int)' with actual type `[a0]'
Expected type: [a0] -> (Int,Int)
  Actual type: [a0] -> [a0]
In the return type of a call of `take'
In the first argument of `map', namely `(take liczbaBomb)'
```

Comment: Do you understand what your error is telling you?

Answer (score 6):

If you remove the type signature and ask GHCi for the type, your problem will be obvious:

```
> :t bombplaces
bombplaces :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

That is, `bombplaces` wants to return a list of lists whereas you want it to return a plain list. You need to either change the type signature, or change the definition of the function, depending on what you want the behaviour to be.

**N.B.** You didn't tell us what definition of `perms` you are using, so I assumed the obvious one.

Comment: I want to get just single list but i don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: @KarolinaMajka this is a very small function, and I'm sure you can figure it out if you carefully consider the types of each component and how they fit together. Try breaking out all the sub-pieces into their own top-level function and giving them each a type signature (after thinking carefully). Also have ghci handy and type e.g. `:t take` to query type signatures.